# How to print a partial stack trace with Log4perl?

Tags: perl, log4perl

With [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl-1.30/lib/Log/Log4perl/Layout/PatternLayout.pm), I know I can include a full stack trace using the %T format string.

Is there a way to print a partial stack trace?  Say, the first N levels?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout::Stacktrace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout::Stacktrace):

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout::Stacktrace;

sub foo { bar() }   
sub bar { baz() }
sub baz { Log::Log4perl->get_logger->warn('baz') }

$ENV{L4P_STACKTRACE_MAX} = 3; # max number of stack frames to show

Log::Log4perl->init('log4perl.conf');
foo();
```

This lets you use the `%S` format specifier in your pattern:

```
log4perl.rootLogger=DEBUG, SCREEN
log4perl.appender.SCREEN=Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout=PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout.ConversionPattern=%S
```

Output:

```
==== START STACK TRACE ===
[1] at ./foo line 10
        __ANON__ (Log::Log4perl::Logger=HASH(0x1a41a68), "baz")
[2] at ./foo line 9
        baz ()
[3] at ./foo line 8
        bar ()
... 1 frames cut off
=== END STACK TRACE ===
```

---

To get something more like what `%T` generates, pass a custom format as a parameter to `%S` (requires Log::Log4perl 1.20 or higher):

```
log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout.ConversionPattern= \
    %S{%s called at %f line %l%[nr!L4P_STACKTRACE_MAX,s=]b}
```

See the documentation for [Stacktrace::Configurable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Stacktrace::Configurable#Format) for the supported format specifiers.

Output:

```
Log::Log4perl::Logger::__ANON__ called at ./foo line 10
main::baz called at ./foo line 9
main::bar called at ./foo line 8
```